# Linq FirstOrDefault with nulllable operator

Tags: c#, linq

When using Linq's FirstOrDefault in combination with the nullable operator, I'm getting an strange behavior.

This is the test case:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication43
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            var x = new List<Test>( );
            x.Add( new Test { x = 1 } );
            x.Add( new Test { x = 2 } );

            var c2 = x.FirstOrDefault( e => e.x == 3 ) ?? x.FirstOrDefault( e => e.x == 1 );


            var a = x.FirstOrDefault( e => e.x == 3 );
            var b = x.FirstOrDefault( e => e.x == 1 );
            var c1 = a ?? b;
        }

        class Test
        {
            public int x;
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect that c1 and c2 both has the same value, but c2 always returns null, even been the right hand side of the nullable operator not null.

There is a similar question, but is related to value type (in that case `doubles`)

[FirstOrDefault() unable to couple with ?? operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476435/firstordefault-unable-to-couple-with-operator)

In this case, is all about the reference type `Test`

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and, as expected, both `c1` and `c2` had a value and were non-null.

Comment: Works for me. Is this really what you are testing or is this a cut down version?

Comment: simpler solution: var c2 = x.FirstOrDefault(e => e.x == 3 || e.x == 1). :)  You are welcome.

Comment: @Johan: That doesn't do the same thing. The original will only return something with x==1 when there are none with x==3 whereas yours will return something with x==1 if it occurs before any x==3.

Comment: Is the same version that I'm trying to run right now. Changed the framework version in the project from 4.0 to 4.5

Comment: @Chris haha I have no idea how I missed that.  Well spotted.  Thanks!

Comment: How are you confirming that c2 is null? you don't seem to have any debug info being outputted... Try adding `Console.WriteLine(c2==null);` in to confirm that you aren't just doing something funny while checking the value.

Comment: @Chris You are right, I was checking the value against the debugger info, but when I print it out to the console, everything was fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had debugger bugs with nullable types. The debugger sometimes displays null when the variable is not null. I believe the C# compiler does some transforms and optimizations when nullable types are involved. The debugger sometimes seems unable to follow.

Use the console to print out the values.

I'm making this an answer because your code should otherwise work ([and Servy has confirmed this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811688/linq-firstordefault-with-nulllable-operator#comment36630171_23811688)). It must be a debugger problem or some other misinterpretation.

Comment: I also went on a similar [wild goose chase](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19026872/314291) once.